# c++ Segmentation Fault using struct pointer

Tags: c++, templates, segmentation-fault

I have a class called Dictionary that contains a key-value pair, a pointer to this key-value pair, and an int that holds the size of the dictionary.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class Dictionary
{
public:

V& operator[](K key);

private:

struct KeyValue
{
    K key;
    V value;
}; //the key-value pair struct

KeyValue* array; //pointer to an array of items (the key-value pairs)

int size; //size of the dictionary (i.e. the array size)
};
```

I am trying to overload the [] operator for this class and when I do so, I get a segmentation fault error

```
template<typename K, typename V>
V& Dictionary<K,V>::operator[](K key){
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (key == array[i].key) {
      return array[i].value;
    }
  }
  array[size].value = 0;
  size++;
  return array[size-1].value;
}
```

I beleive that the seg fault is occuring in this line

```
array[size].value = 0;
```

However, I don't know exactly why it's happening. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are reimplementing [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (*badly*). Why would you do that rather than just using `std::map`?

Comment: Just because the program crashes on this line doesn't mean that's where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your program, which is why stackoverflow.com's [help] instructs you to provide a [mre], otherwise it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you. See [ask] for mroe information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an array in C and C++ has `N` elements, the valid indexes are:  `0, 1, 2, ... N-1`.  In contrast `N` is not a valid index:  it is *past* the end of the array.

In this particular case, the *last* element of `array` is `array[size - 1]`:

```
array[0]         // first element
array[1]         // second element
// ...
array[size - 2]  // second-to-last element
array[size - 1]  // last element

array[size]      // error: beyond the last element
```

Using `array[size]` is accessing *beyond* the end of the array and results in a segmentation fault.

In the bigger picture, if you need to *add* elements to an array and you are out of space in the array, you would need to allocate a new array with larger size, and move (or copy) elements from the old array to the new array.

This is "reallocating", and this is what `std::vector<T>` does when it grows beyond its current capacity.

You may want to replace your use of a dynamic array with an `std::vector<KeyValue>`.  That would let the `std::vector` take care of these operations.

Comment: This assumes that `array` was actually alocated for `size` elements, and there aren't any additional reserve capacity (like what `std::vector` does). There's nothing in the question to support this assumption. The question is unanswerable without a [mre].

Comment: I have also tried incrementing size first and then calling array[size-1] however this also results in a segmentation fault

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, that is correct, I made that assumption based on the comment in the questioner's code:  `//size of the dictionary (i.e. the array size)`

Comment: @ZacharyRudebeck, the segmentation fault is expected in that case:  the array index is equal to the size of the array, which means it is an *invalid* index.  Just incrementing the variable `size` does not increase the size of the array.  You need to allocate a new array with a larger size, or use `std::vector` which takes care of this for you.